# Keep GUI from running at boot in Raspbian?

Tags: gui, headless

I started running my Raspberry Pi with a monitor and keyboard, but I ended up decapitating it and don't need the GUI running anymore. How do I make it not start at boot?

Comment: What OS are you running? Assuming you are running a recent version of Raspbian you can run sudo raspi-config and select boot options from the menu and then console.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Thanks. Will the GUI still run in the background though?

Comment: No, you have to manually start it with startx, you can verify that by running the followinf ps aux it will show all the running processes no matter who owns the process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by steve use raspi-config for setting up the GUI.

Steps
1. on the prompt type

```
sudo raspi-config
```

2. Step 2 Select the option highlighted "Boot Option"

[image]

3. Step 3 Based on your need select "Option B1/ Option B2".

[image]

4. Step 4 - Click on finish and the prompt will ask for system Reboot. The system will boot to console from now on.

[image]